# How can I link enum parameter 1 to the type of parameter 3

Tags: typescript

The base structure I'm looking for is this:

```
interface ProfileModel { name: string; } // dummy example

export enum Tokens {
  profile = 'profile'
}

export interface TokenToTypeMap {
  [Tokens.profile]: ProfileModel;
}

type Store = {
  [key in Tokens]: Record<string, TokenToTypeMap[key]>;
}
```

The idea is that a property in `Store` is a `Tokens` type.
The value of that property is an object like `{ [id: string]: matching type from the TokenToTypeMap }`

I try to implement it (unsuccesfully) like this:

```
class StoreService {
  private store: Store = { 
    [Tokens.profile]: {} 
  };

  public setValue <T extends Tokens> (token: T, id: string, object: TokenToTypeMap[T]): void {
    this.store[token][id] = object; // error occurs here
  }
}
```

Error thrown:

```
store.service.ts(41,5): error TS2536: Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'Store[T]'.
```

The problem seems to be that `T extends Tokens`, which becomes clear with this change:

```
  public setValue <T extends Tokens> (token: T, id: string, object: TokenToTypeMap[T]): void {
    token = Tokens.profile;
    this.store[token][id] = object;
  }
```

resulting in the error:

```
store.service.ts(41,5): error TS2322: Type 'Tokens' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'Tokens' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Tokens'.
```

Whereas this actually compiles:

```
  public setValue <T extends Tokens> (token: T, id: string, object: TokenToTypeMap[T]): void {
    const x = Tokens.profile;
    this.store[x][id] = object;
  }
```

I think syntactically I should be looking for this functionality to fix it:

```
public setValue <T is one of the Tokens> (token: T, id: string, object: TokenToTypeMap[T]): void
```

But is this technically possible? The `token` argument must be a `Tokens` type, and the `object` argument must be the type associated with the `token` argument.

Comment: As a workaround you can use `this.store[token as Tokens][id] = `.

Comment: thanks @AaronBeall, that at least removes my blocker on this.